# Spring MVC Interceptor error response result in blank page

Tags: spring-mvc, http-error

In my spring MVC app (3.1.4-release, Servlet 2.5), 
I am not able to display a custom 403 error page when trigger from my HandlerInterceptorAdapter.

My web.xml :

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/403</location>
</error-page>
```

My Error Controller :

```
@Controller
public class HTTPErrorController {

 @RequestMapping(value="403")
 public ModelAndView error403(){     
     return new ModelAndView("/errors/403");
 }

 @RequestMapping(value="404")
 public ModelAndView error404(){     
     return new ModelAndView("/errors/404");
 }
}
```

My Handler interceptor :

```
public class CSRFHandlerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    // Validate CSRF token on POST request only.        
    if (request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("post")) {
        if (!CSRFTokenManager.verifyCSRFToken(request)) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Bad or missing CSRF value");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

When the sendError is sent, I have a blank page in firefox and in Ie.
404 exception is working correctly but can't figure out how to make the 403 display my custom error page.

Firefox screenshot: 
http://hpics.li/8b6ab9f

Httpfox screenshot :
http://hpics.li/b032ca0

** I am using apache-tomcat-7.0.42

Thanks

Comment: Can you inspect the request/response in firebug and post what you see when  sending a 403 response

Comment: I added 2 screen shots links. Can't post images yet.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem.

For my situation, I figured out it is because my error page do response.forward and than goto Interceptor again. (infinite loop)

i.e., You can try to simplify your /error/403 page to plaintext: "Here is 403".